# Doctrine building querybuilder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to make topic / comment system with symfony and I have some question about doctrine's querybuilder.

if I have two entities connected:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Topicit", inversedBy="comments")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="topic_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $topicit;
```

and

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="topicit")
*/
protected $comments;
```

Currently I have builder (getting every column):

```
$repository = $this -> getDoctrine() -> getRepository('FTFairyBundle:Comment');

        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')        
          ->orderBy('p.topicit', 'ASC')
          ->getQuery();

      $comment = $query ->getResult();
```

How I make it get only wanted `topic_id`? Like if I open page with id #1 I wanna get comments connected to that id.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use query builder for that kind of tasks, you can simply use a getter in your `Topicit` entity (that of course you need to retrieve from DB)

Something like `->getComments()`  *(of course that method needs to be defined in `Topic` class)

Doctrine will take care of load only "consistent" data from your `Topic` object

---

#### Method definition

```
public getComments()
{
    return $this->comments;
}
```

If you want to query directly you can modify your code as follows

```
$topicit_id = ... //code to retrieve topicit_id

$repository = $this->getDoctrine()-> getRepository('FTFairyBundle:Comment');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.topicit = :topicit_id')
    ->setParameter('topicit_id', $topicit_id)
    ->orderBy('p.topicit', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();

$comment = $query ->getResult();
```